# CLI command for Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache

Tags: magento2

Which CLI commands are executed when pressing this button in system/Cache Management?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no command executed when click that button.
If you dive into code, you'll see they use `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\MergeService` to `cleanMergedJsCss` in `pub/static/_cache/merged` folder